# Magento2 Need understanding of following code related to invoice

Tags: magento2, invoice

```
 $transactionSave = $transaction->addObject($invoice)->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
            $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
            $transactionSave->save();
```

I just wanted to understand what this code does because I don't see any function to send invoice email in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$transactionSave = $transaction->addObject($invoice)->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
```

> In Magento 2, transactions are used to perform operations on objects
> and persist changes to the database. Here, a transaction object is
> being created and stored in the variable $transactionSave.
>
> The addObject() method is used to add objects to the transaction. In
> this case, two objects are being added: $invoice and
> $invoice->getOrder(). The getOrder() method likely retrieves the
> associated order object of the invoice.
>
> The method of chaining allows for adding multiple objects to the
> transaction in a single line.

```
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
```

> This line accesses the order object associated with the invoice
> ($invoice->getOrder()) and calls the setIsInProcess() method on it.
>
> The purpose of this line is to set the "IsInProcess" flag of the order
> to true. This flag might be a custom attribute or a property that
> indicates whether the order is currently being processed.

```
$transactionSave->save();
```

> This line saves the transaction, committing the changes made to the
> objects within it to the database.
>
> The save() method is likely a Magento 2 transaction method that
> persists the changes made to the objects added to the transaction.

**Send Invoice Email using CRON:**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Cron;

use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\InvoiceFactory;

class SendInvoiceEmailCron implements \Magento\Framework\Console\Cli
{
    /**
     * @var InvoiceSender
     */
    protected $invoiceSender;

    /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    protected $state;

    /**
     * SendInvoiceEmailCron constructor.
     * @param InvoiceSender $invoiceSender
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param State $state
     */
    public function __construct(
        InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        State $state,
        InvoiceFactory $invoiceFactory
    ) {
        $this->invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->invoiceFactory = $invoiceFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Execute cron job to send invoice email.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_FRONTEND); // Set the area code to frontend

        
            $invoiceId = 123; // Replace with the actual invoice ID

            $invoice = $this->invoiceFactory->create()->load($invoiceId);

            // Send the invoice email
            $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice);

            echo "Invoice email sent successfully.";
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo "Error occurred while sending invoice email: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Is it any way related to send Invoice email or set Invoice Email to CRON for sending the Invoice email when CRON runs ?

Comment: Do you mean to send an invoice email in CRON? Correct?

Comment: yes @Ronak I wanted to know that

Comment: I added a code for the invoice email sent can you please check?

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that but I thought that code which I added might add in CRON

Comment: Okay. Accept the answer if you are satisfied with the answer so it's useful for other users also. Thanks

Comment: Without this send code is there anyway to send Invoice?